# always redirected to a different url when download is done programmatically (Java)

Tags: java, redirect, download, apache-commons

This is what I need to do.
I need to download a bunch of apks from a market.
Analyze each file if it contains ads inside using Multi-apk tool and compress it again (This is not the issue so I won'd discuss it any further)

Right now, I'm doing the part wherein I will download apk from a particular market.
I get the source code of the page and get all URLS that ends with .APK

After each URL is extracted from the page, I download it using commons io.
However, whenever a download is complete, I noticed that all of them is the same in size. Which makes me think that it is downloading the same file.

I tried using wget, and I found out that all of the urls are redirected to one url.

When I go to page and download that same file by clicking the button that says "download to PC", it works properly and downloaded the file that I want.

Is there any way that I could download the files that I want? Can I modify something to the code to get the correct APK? Is this one of the capability in web programming?

Here's the code that downloads the APK

```
private static void downloadSample(String directLink) throws Exception
    {
        String[] getAPKName = directLink.split("/");
        System.out.println(getAPKName[getAPKName.length -1]);
        String APKName = getAPKName[getAPKName.length -1];        
        org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(directLink), new File("C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication21\\APK\\"
+ APKName));

    }
```

Comment: You need to look at the cookies given when the page is first loaded. There is probably a mechanism there to prevent exactly this sort of thing...

Comment: You could use firebug for it, what bmorris said. On the network tab you can track what post/get request sends to the server.

Comment: @jpee I tried using firebug, It displays the request used to get the images in webpage but not the request used to get the APKs that I want . Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way that I could download the files that I want? Can I modify something to the code to get the correct APK? Is this one of the capability in web programming?

Technically, yes there is a way, but we can't tell you what it is.  Basically, you have figure out what it is about your Java requests that is causing the server to act differently to when you make the request from a browser.  Looking at the browser requests using FireBug (or equivalent) would be a good start.  It would also be worthwhile examining the file that you are downloading (from Java) to see what it contains.  It might be an error message or a notice or something.

However, you should also consider *why* the server has been set up to do this.

- Have you checked the Terms and Conditions of the site?
- Is what your doing in accordance with them?
- Do you have permission to do what you are doing?

Comment: The file that I get from the directlink/URL that I am redirected to is an apk as well. It is the market's app for downloading the APKs. I checked the Terms of Use of the website, but it didn't mention anything about how someone desires to download the apks. And they provide a button to download it in the PC so I guess there's nothing wrong with what I do. Can you tell me now how to make my code work? :p Thanks!